# Needing to Search by TN and by date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Column A = Due Date

Column B = Cust TN - Phone number in 2234567890 format (all together with area code and the 7 digits)

I'm trying to find 6/26/15 rows. But some rows won't have the Due Date populated as the picture shows but the TN will be the same. Ideally, I could paste a formula in each cell/row. If it could just find the date that is tied with that number and populate it in the cell, that could work for me so I could then sort by date. If I sort by date now, the extra lines will be lost and I can't lose that data since it was pulled from another database.

So if we made a blank column C, I couldnt figure out how to make it say take this phone number and find the another cell with this number with the date populated and put this date here.

So what we would have if you view the image would be

C2: 2/6/2015

C3: 2/6/2015

C4: 2/6/2015

C5: 2/6/2015

C6: 2/6/2015

C7: 2/6/2015

C8: 6/26/2015

C9: 6/26/2015

Is there a search function that could easily do this? Then I can sort by date then by TN.

[image: Example of list]

I appreciate it! I'm stuck!

PS. In the event the picture for some reason doesn't load, I'll try my best to format column A and B on here.

A1 = Due Date

B1 = Cust TN

A4 = 2/6/2015

A5 = 2/6/2015

A7 = 2/6/2015

A9 = 6/26/2015

B2 = 5551112222

B3 = 5551112222

B4 = 5551112222

B5 = 5551112222

B6 - B7 = 5550001212

B8 - B9 = 5554441212

Comment: Is this a one off situation or are you looking for a continuous process? If this is a one off my suggestion would be to AutoFilter your 2 columns and filtering out (not permanently though) all rows with blank cells. Then copy the remaining lines to another sheet so they have Date/TN with no empty dates. Then going back and unfiltering the raw data and adding a temp column you can search for the TN using `VLOOKUP` and return the date. Hope this guides you in the right direction.

Comment: I see where you were going with this. It would work in theory but it wouldn't do as intended. I've been given a spreadsheet where two databases have been merged together. One database has the date on it and one doesn't. The only thing they both have in common is the TN. Of course the rows are larger, but my job is to find mismatches in all the rows. So by doing the way you suggested, I'm actually just isolating one database from the rest. To answer the question, it will be a reoccuring process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this site to answer the question.

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=25239

In the event the page cannot be displayed, I had to create a VBA code to find the values. It did something funky in the cell for the ones that were blanks. So a lot of them showed up with:  , , 6/26/2015  or whatever date matched the cells.

Shift + F11 and insert module

```
Public Function FindSeries(TRange As Range, MatchWith As String) 

For Each cell In TRange 
    If cell.Value = MatchWith Then 
        x = x & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value & ", " 
    End If 
Next cell 

FindSeries = Left(x, (Len(x) - 2)) 

End Function
```

And back on the spreadsheet, I added but within my specs needed.

```
=findseries(A1:A7,A1) or =findseries(A1:B7,"abc") where
```

"A1:A7 contains the lookup values

A1 contains the text string you want to look for

B1:B7 contains the values you want to return"

To make it work for me since I don't know VBA at all and since this code basically finds all instances of a column (the TNs) and returns all values to the right of it, I just added the dates on the right side. Then I removed the weird spaces and commas, and sorted by that column. Then took out the dates I didnt need and I was in business.

Thank you for everyone else that assisted otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

First, sort the data so that the completed Due Dates appear at the top.

[image: Sorted WS]

Then enter the following formula in A6 and fill downwards:

`=INDEX(A2:A5,(MATCH(B6,B2:B5,0)))`

The general formula for your scenario is:

`=INDEX(**Range of cells with due dates in them**,(MATCH(**CustTN**,**Range of CustTNs that are adjacent to the cells with due dates in them,0)))`